# Server nics on two subnets: gateway?

Tags: subnet, local-area-network, nic

Server is connected two two separate, isolated subnets via two physical nics.  Is there any way the server can act as a gateway for the two networks to communicate?  To clarify, I don't want any communication.  The goal is just to provide the same web services to both subnets from the server only, without allowing it to connect the two in any way.

Network A is a typical office LAN.  Network B is in the same building but isolated.  No internet access, nothing.  It needs to remain that way for a variety of proprietary reasons.  Users developing software must upload it to a subversion server via N A.  Technicians on N B must be able to access the subversion files.  My switches on both subnets are Procurve 2810 ...no ACL support I don't think.

Comment: Are these two subnets physically isolated or two vlans? I am trying to understand the security requirements here, if you are providing identical services would a collection of ACLs not be more appropriate? By default most servers do not act as routers, but most can if configured to do so, either maliciously or accidentally.

Comment: Original question edited for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe it, you don't actually want the server to be a gateway.  An IP gateway is a host that forwards traffic for the local network segment to other hosts that don't reside on the segment.  It's only a gateway if it is routing traffic, which you've stated you don't want it to do.  Don't enable forwarding or bridging.

However, you can run the web services or subversion on both IP interfaces.  As long as the address for the interface is on the same subnet as the client, the client won't need a gateway. You just need to configure the web server to listen on both interfaces.

Comment: Okay, that is the current config and I am glad to have a few telling me I am go to go like this.  Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 2):

> Server is connected two two separate, isolated subnets via two physical nics. Is there any way the server can act as a gateway for the two networks to communicate?  The goal is just to provide the same web services to both subnets from the server only, without allowing it to connect the two in any way.

The server doesn't need to be a gateway.  Just bind subversion to both NICs and have people connect to subversion at the respective server NIC  ip address.

Comment: I don't think you read my question very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If *IP Forwarding* is not enabled in the OS, it will not route packets between networks.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve: Give the server two NICs. Connect one to subnet A and the other one to subnet B. And then make sure, that "IP forwarding" on that server is securely disabled! In addition to:
    echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
you can also set the default rule of the FORWARD chain to drop:
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP
Check your specific OS instructions on how to achieve these. Usually, the 0 into ip_forward is the default anyways, though.

Comment: Thanks Kai.  I like your idea of explicitly dropping packets that somehow make their way through.